# How to upgrade Vagrant?

Tags: upgrade, virtualbox, vagrant

I have Vagrant 1.8.1 installed but apparently I need a higher version

[image: Vagrant version 1.9.0 required]

As instructed [here on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/845987/how-do-i-upgrade-vagrant-to-last-version-in-ubuntu) I downloaded the latest release 2.0.1, opened it and pressed install, but nothing has changed.

[image: Vagrant version]

I also did `apt-get update` but nothing changed.

How can I upgrade vagrant?

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command did the work for me:

```
sudo dpkg -i vagrant_2.0.1_x86_64.deb
```